# Android c2dm registration id format

Tags: php, android, regex, android-c2dm

I suspect I am going to feel really stupid after posting this but here goes.  I have two main questions:

1) What is an appropriate regex to use for the registration id?  Currently I have the following but I have not been able to find any docs to support whether this is sufficient:

```
'/^[a-z0-9_-]{40,255}$/i'
```

2) Is it "valid" for a regID to contain "--"?  I know that android can't go worrying about what every language - in this case mysql - uses for comments, etc. but this caught me a little off guard.  Up to this point I had always flagged that in my sanitizer(s) because of the possibility of being used for sql injection.

Comment: Like Seva Alekseyev says, the format of the C2DM registration ID can change at any time, so using a regex for this would not necessarily be the best solution. If your only worry is storing in MySQL, there's no need to do this validation. Instead consider [`mysqli_prepare()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) for your MySQL statements to avoid SQL injection. Personally I prefer `mysqli_prepare()` over `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: I think you got the best possible answer you need to accept it

Comment: @dilip - Sorry, I have been away.  Accepted

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The format of the registration ID is an implementation detail. Google might change it anytime without any notice. Why do you want to validate it? If storing in MySQL is a concern, use mysql_real_escape_string() just in case, or mysqli::real_escape_string() with mysqli on PHP, or parameters.

It's like people's names. You might think it's all alphabetic, then O'Neil comes along. Escape it just in case.

Comment: Exactly. Escape the inputs properly and there is no SQL injection to worry about.